# Tuning Mysql MyISAM tables and queries

Tags: mysql

**Folks**

I have tables ( with their structures)

Billing_datas_new has about 50 million records and it increases on daily basis. ( the call detail records) are dumped in this table along with the required ids)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cctonumbers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `countrycode_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `dialcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `effectivedate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `route_code` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `effectivedate` (`effectivedate`),
  KEY `parentid` (`parentid`),
  KEY `number` (`number`),
  KEY `dialcode` (`dialcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15729 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `billing_datas_NEW` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batch_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `switch_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carrierid_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `technical_profileid_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `carrierid_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `technical_profileid_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `billing_increment_supplier` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `billing_increment_customer` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `billable_duration_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `call_duration_seconds` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `billable_duration_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `destination_country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `rateplanid_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rateplanid_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_total_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_total_customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate_effective_date_supplier` date NOT NULL,
  `rate_effective_date_customer` date NOT NULL,
  `call_hour` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sequence_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `record_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `connection_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `release_cause` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `start_time_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `answer_time_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `release_tod` datetime NOT NULL,
  `greenwich_mean_time` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `release_cause_protocol_stack` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `binary_value_protocol_stack` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `first_release_dialogue` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `origination_trunkid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voip_protocol` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `source_number` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `source_host_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `destination_number` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `destination_host_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `callid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `remote_payload_ipaddress` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `remote_payload_udpaddress` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `local_payload_ipaddress` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `local_payload_udpaddress` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `codec_list` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_packets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `egress_packets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_octets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `egress_octets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_packet_loss` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_delay` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_packet_jitter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplierid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `protocol` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `termination_source_number` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_source_host` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_destination_number` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_destination_host_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_callid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_remote_payload_ipaddress` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `termination_remote_payload_udpaddress` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `termination_local_payload_ipaddress` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `termination_local_payload_udpaddress` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `termination_codec_list` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `termination_ingress_packets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_egress_packets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_ingress_octets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_egress_octets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_ingress_packet_loss` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_ingress_delay` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `termination_ingress_packet_jitter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `final_route_indication` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `routing_digits` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `call_duration` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `post_dial_delay` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `ring_time` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `call_duration_ms` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `confid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `rpid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `route_entry_index` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `route_table_used` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `lnp_dipped` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `ingress_lrn` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `egress_lrn` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `cnam_dipped` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `dnc_dipped` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `origination_device_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `termination_device_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ers_dipped` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `oli_digits` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `routing_match` varchar(41) NOT NULL,
  `termination_pdd` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `proxy_charge_information` varchar(41) NOT NULL,
  `jurisdictoinal_indication_parameter` varchar(41) NOT NULL,
  `matched_digits_ers` varchar(41) NOT NULL,
  `route_table_irs` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `route_sequence_number_ers` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `jurisdiction_type_ers` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `switch_id` (`switch_id`),
  KEY `carrieridsupplier` (`carrierid_supplier`),
  KEY `technicalprofileidsupplier` (`technical_profileid_supplier`),
  KEY `carrieridcustomer` (`carrierid_customer`),
  KEY `technicalprofileidcustomer` (`technical_profileid_customer`),
  KEY `destination` (`destination`),
  KEY `destinationcountry` (`destination_country`),
  KEY `rateplanidsupplier` (`rateplanid_supplier`),
  KEY `rateplanidcustomer` (`rateplanid_customer`),
  KEY `callhour` (`call_hour`),
  KEY `recordtype` (`record_type`),
  KEY `connectiontype` (`connection_type`),
  KEY `sessionid` (`session_id`),
  KEY `releasecause` (`release_cause`),
  KEY `starttimedate` (`start_time_date`),
  KEY `protocolstack` (`release_cause_protocol_stack`),
  KEY `binaryvalue` (`binary_value_protocol_stack`),
  KEY `originationtrunkid` (`origination_trunkid`),
  KEY `sourcehostname` (`source_host_name`),
  KEY `destinationhostname` (`destination_host_name`),
  KEY `supplierid` (`supplierid`),
  KEY `terminationsourcehost` (`termination_source_host`),
  KEY `terminationdestinationhostname` (`termination_destination_host_name`),
  KEY `callduration` (`call_duration`),
  KEY `postdialdelay` (`post_dial_delay`),
  KEY `batch_id` (`batch_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=56232766 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carriermasters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `carriername` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `carriershortname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fax` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `billingaddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `billingcity` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `billingstate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `billingcountry` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `minimumseconds` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `incrementseconds` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedby` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `account_manager` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `carriershortname` (`carriershortname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=306 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `technicalprofiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `carrier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profilename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `createdby` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedby` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `carrier_id` (`carrier_id`),
  KEY `profilename` (`profilename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=479 ;
```

MY.CNF for the server is as below

```
# Example MySQL config file for very large systems.
#
# This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 3G
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 1024M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 256M

max_connections = 100   
max_heap_table_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 1024M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 3G
slow_query_log



# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin
#
# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 100M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 3G
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 1024M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

mysql tuner report is  as below

```
-- MYSQL PERFORMANCE TUNING PRIMER --
         - By: Matthew Montgomery -

MySQL Version 5.1.69-log x86_64

Uptime = 1 days 9 hrs 7 min 0 sec
Avg. qps = 13
Total Questions = 1616144
Threads Connected = 2

Warning: Server has not been running for at least 48hrs.
It may not be safe to use these recommendations

To find out more information on how each of these
runtime variables effects performance visit:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html
Visit http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/advisors.html
for info about MySQL's Enterprise Monitoring and Advisory Service

SLOW QUERIES
The slow query log is enabled.
Current long_query_time = 10.000000 sec.
You have 30 out of 1616167 that take longer than 10.000000 sec. to complete
Your long_query_time seems to be fine

BINARY UPDATE LOG
The binary update log is enabled
The expire_logs_days is not set.
The mysqld will retain the entire binary log until RESET MASTER or PURGE MASTER LOGS commands are run manually
Setting expire_logs_days will allow you to remove old binary logs automatically
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/purge-master-logs.html
Binlog sync is not enabled, you could loose binlog records during a server crash

WORKER THREADS
Current thread_cache_size = 8
Current threads_cached = 6
Current threads_per_sec = 0
Historic threads_per_sec = 0
Your thread_cache_size is fine

MAX CONNECTIONS
Current max_connections = 100
Current threads_connected = 2
Historic max_used_connections = 9
The number of used connections is 9% of the configured maximum.
You are using less than 10% of your configured max_connections.
Lowering max_connections could help to avoid an over-allocation of memory
See "MEMORY USAGE" section to make sure you are not over-allocating

INNODB STATUS
Current InnoDB index space = 3 M
Current InnoDB data space = 20 M
Current InnoDB buffer pool free = 0 %
Current innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8 M
Depending on how much space your innodb indexes take up it may be safe
to increase this value to up to 2 / 3 of total system memory

MEMORY USAGE
Max Memory Ever Allocated : 15.14 G
Configured Max Per-thread Buffers : 132.05 G
Configured Max Global Buffers : 3.25 G
Configured Max Memory Limit : 135.31 G
Physical Memory : 7.68 G

Max memory limit exceeds 90% of physical memory

KEY BUFFER
Current MyISAM index space = 16.92 G
Current key_buffer_size = 3.00 G
Key cache miss rate is 1 : 2326
Key buffer free ratio = 0 %
You could increase key_buffer_size
It is safe to raise this up to 1/4 of total system memory;
assuming this is a dedicated database server.

QUERY CACHE
Query cache is enabled
Current query_cache_size = 256 M
Current query_cache_used = 2 M
Current query_cache_limit = 256 M
Current Query cache Memory fill ratio = .94 %
Current query_cache_min_res_unit = 4 K
Your query_cache_size seems to be too high.
Perhaps you can use these resources elsewhere
MySQL won't cache query results that are larger than query_cache_limit in size

SORT OPERATIONS
Current sort_buffer_size = 256 M
Current read_rnd_buffer_size = 64 M
Sort buffer seems to be fine

JOINS
Current join_buffer_size = 8.00 M
You have had 408 queries where a join could not use an index properly
You have had 5836 joins without keys that check for key usage after each row
join_buffer_size >= 4 M
This is not advised
You should enable "log-queries-not-using-indexes"
Then look for non indexed joins in the slow query log.

OPEN FILES LIMIT
Current open_files_limit = 2158 files
The open_files_limit should typically be set to at least 2x-3x
that of table_cache if you have heavy MyISAM usage.
Your open_files_limit value seems to be fine

TABLE CACHE
Current table_open_cache = 1024 tables
Current table_definition_cache = 256 tables
You have a total of 119 tables
You have 175 open tables.
The table_cache value seems to be fine

TEMP TABLES
Current max_heap_table_size = 64 M
Current tmp_table_size = 1.00 G
Of 209033 temp tables, 7% were created on disk
Effective in-memory tmp_table_size is limited to max_heap_table_size.
Created disk tmp tables ratio seems fine

TABLE SCANS
Current read_buffer_size = 1.00 G
Current table scan ratio = 35358 : 1
read_buffer_size is over 8 MB there is probably no need for such a large read_buffer

TABLE LOCKING
Current Lock Wait ratio = 1 : 61064
Your table locking seems to be fine
```

The stored procedure is as attached

```
BEGIN

create temporary table if not exists temp_cns (id int primary key, countryname varchar(255));
insert into temp_cns select c1.id, c2.countryname from cctonumbers c1 left join countrycodes c2 on c1.countrycode_id = c2.id;


drop temporary table if exists temp_cause_code_id;

SET @temp_ids = CONCAT('create temporary table temp_cause_code_id select id from billing_datas_NEW use index(primary) where ', conditions_str);
PREPARE stmt FROM @temp_ids;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

drop temporary table if exists temp_cause_code_allfileds;

create temporary table temp_cause_code_allfileds select m_tbl.id,m_tbl.destination,(select dialcode from cctonumbers where id = m_tbl.destination) as dial_code,(select number from cctonumbers where id = m_tbl.destination_country) as country_value,m_tbl.destination_country,m_tbl.release_cause_protocol_stack, m_tbl.binary_value_protocol_stack, m_tbl.release_cause,m_tbl.call_duration_seconds, m_tbl.destination_country as destination_name,m_tbl.start_time_date,m_tbl.start_time_date as start_date,m_tbl.carrierid_customer,m_tbl.technical_profileid_customer,m_tbl.origination_trunkid,m_tbl.carrierid_supplier,m_tbl.technical_profileid_supplier,m_tbl.supplierid,cm.carriername as customer,ctech.profilename as customer_tech,(select carriername from carriermasters where id = carrierid_supplier) as vendor,(select profilename from technicalprofiles where id = technical_profileid_supplier) as vendor_tech_profile from temp_cause_code_id as temp_ids LEFT JOIN billing_datas_NEW  as m_tbl  ON temp_ids.id = m_tbl.id LEFT JOIN carriermasters as cm ON m_tbl.carrierid_customer = cm.id LEFT JOIN technicalprofiles as ctech ON m_tbl.technical_profileid_customer = ctech.id WHERE m_tbl.id IS NOT NULL;

drop temporary table if exists temp_group_records; 

SET @sqlv = CONCAT('create temporary table temp_group_records select destination,dial_code,country_value, start_date, destination_country, release_cause_protocol_stack, binary_value_protocol_stack, release_cause, destination_name, count(*) as calls, (sum(call_duration_seconds) / 60) as durations, sum(call_duration_seconds > 0) as scalls,customer,customer_tech,vendor,vendor_tech_profile from temp_cause_code_allfileds  group by binary_value_protocol_stack, release_cause_protocol_stack, destination, destination_country ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlv;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

update temp_group_records set destination = destination_country where destination = '';

update temp_group_records t, temp_cns c set t.destination_name = c.countryname where t.destination = c.id;

drop table if exists temp_records;

create table temp_records select customer,customer_tech,vendor,vendor_tech_profile,release_cause_protocol_stack, binary_value_protocol_stack,dial_code,country_value, release_cause, destination_name, sum(calls) as ncalls, sum(durations) as ndurations, sum(scalls) as nscalls,start_date from temp_group_records group by binary_value_protocol_stack, release_cause_protocol_stack, destination_name;

END
```

The condition_str in the above stored procedure along with its explain in mysql is in the link as below

http://www.prosesindia.com/dock.docx

The problem is

when i run the above stored procedure , it takes about 1 min and 40 seconds.

is there any way we can tune the stored procedure or the server variables.

Comment: A short description of what your procedure does, in natural language, would be welcome. Alternatively, comment your code. I suspect your whole procedure could be rewritten as a single query, but I am not enclined to guessing what your code tries to do.

Comment: randomseed : basically we are generating the reports based on the date from billing_datas_new table using the stored procedure. the problem is billing_datas_new table has inserts going on every 15 minutes and is myisam engine and when we are using stored procedure  that has select queries , the billing_datas_new table is locked. so we are in catch 22 scenario. the reports takes forever to generate.

Comment: You need to describe *the algorithm*, or the business rules.

Comment: Please provide a description of the results generated by your procedure. It seems that all you want to do is extract some data based on some rules. The right solution is likely to be a whole new approach. But your code is difficult to read, so we need you to comment your code and describe your procedure. Help us help you.

Comment: Hello randomseed : thanks for your support  I have added the detailed documentation of the stored procedure on our site  http://www.prosesindia.com/randomseed.docx

Comment: is there any particular reason that you do not use innodb instead of myisam? so that whole table would not be locked during this process..

Comment: we tried to use innodb in past and had a bad experience with the query performance.

Comment: I don't see any reason for down votes. It is ridiculous. +1. Helpful question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't really understand why you would do your reporting on apparantly operative data sources. Have you thought of creating a Data Warehouse out of your existing structures? These are normally modelled in a way which supports the adhoc queries you want to run.

I really don't see to reason to do reporting via stored procedures in a way you used it. Have a look at ETL tools like Talend Open Studio, with them you can do the processing of the data *before* you load it in the database.

If you want to carry on with the way you do it now, I'd first recommend to look at the query which populates the table *temp_cause_code_allfileds* You use a lot of subselects there, which are evaluated on a per-record basis. I guess it woulf make much more sense to do this via a general LEFT OUTER JOIN for each table queried.

Answer (score 1):

After staring at it for some time I can say that there are not much you could do to make it run faster.

Regarding server tuning you could ensure the temp drive is on a separate disk not partition and has plenty of space.

You could also run weekly or monthly table optimizations if you have tables that have records added and deleted quite often and in high number.

Also if you have old data that can be scrapped it would be good to take it out.

Last, I would suggest adding the back-tick around all tables and fields, adding semi-colon at the end and upper case all commands. I have seen this helping to shave a small amount of time of queries. But this does not have any affect on the procedure code, just queries from your programming language.